# How to get 6GB/S with an AData SSD on an Asus P8 Z68-V Pro

Tags: ssd

I have a Asus P8 Z68-V Pro motherboard and an AData S599 100GB SSD connected to the Marvel SATA port using a 6BG/S cable.  The boot screen reports a speed of 3GB/S for this.  How do I set it to 6GB/S?

Update: the drive is plugged into one of the 6GB/S connectors (number 9 in the diagram in Paul's response).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same board. The ones on the right-hand side are the SATA-6GB/s ports, they are gray. The SATA-3GB/s are the blue ones.

Refer to this diagram, 9 and 10. Depending on what case you purchased, they can be a little awkward to get to:

[image]

[Your main issue here is that your SSD processor doesn't support 6GB/s](http://www.sandforce.com/index.php?id=19&parentId=2).

When you get an SSD that does support 6GB/s, the following might be of use:

If the same behavior occurs when plugged into 10, [update your Marvell driver](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_PRO/#download). Number 9 is the Marvell SATA controller, 10 is the native Intel SATA controller.

Also, bear in mind that the Marvell controller is not for booting from, use the Intel SATA controller on 10 for that.

Comment: It's plugged into 9 in the diagram.  I've updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: Updated my answer with pertinent information.

Comment: Nice one, thanks Paul.  I hadn't even considered that it didn't support 6GB/S!  Oh well, off to the shop again...

Answer (score 1):

Your SSD doesn't support 6GB/s transfers.  According to [ADATA's specs](http://www.adata.com.tw/?action=product_feature&cid=&piid=33) it uses as Sandforce 1222 controller and [Sandforce's specs](http://www.sandforce.com/index.php?id=19&parentId=2) show that the 1200 series only support 3 GB/s transfers.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably different colored SATA ports on the motherboard. Make sure that you're plugging the SSD into a SATA3 (6Gbps) port instead of the SATA2 (3Gbps)

OFF TOPIC: What size of SSD is it? I've played around with Intel's Smart Response Technology and am very impressed at it's speeds.

Just to give you an idea of SRT. My current configuration is:

```
SRT Cache: 1x64GB SATA3 SSD
Raid 0: 2x500GB SATA2 7200RPM HDD
```

I copied a large VM image from the hard drive (SRT + RAID0) to another SSD drive.

[image]

If you've not played around with it or don't know what it is, It's where you use 20GB up to 64GB of a SSD to cache the data on your physical platter hard drive. When it gets a chance, it will write back to the HDD from the SSD.